# How can I trigger events of ActiveHandler class in botframework v4 node sdk

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have gone through Bot v4 documentation and felt very surprised and happy by looking into Events of ActivityHandler class. But I am unable to trigger some of them in my bot through Facebook channel.

I have tried below code in my class which extends ActivityHandler class. Below mentioned events unable to trigger. In fact, I dont know how to trigger these events.

onEvent
onMembersRemoved
onReactionsAdded
onReactionsRemoved
onMessageReaction
onTokenResponseEvent
onUnrecognizedActivityType

Below is the code Snippet.

```
class DialogBot extends ActivityHandler {
 constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger,conversationReferences) {
        super();

        }

 this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {

            console.log('=========== from onEvent funcion from class=====');
         await next();
        });

 this.onMembersRemoved(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onMembersRemoved---- ');
          await next();
        }); 

  this.onMessageReaction(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onMessageReaction---- ');
          await next();
        }); 

this.onReactionsAdded(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onReactionsAdded---- ');
          await next();
        }); 

  this.onReactionsRemoved(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onReactionsRemoved---- ');
         await next();
        }); 

     this.onTokenResponseEvent(async (context, next) => {
              console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onTokenResponseEvent---- ');
            await next();
        }) ; 

           this.onUnrecognizedActivityType(async (context, next) => {
      console.log('----dialog bot.js ----onUnrecognizedActivityType---- ');

            await next();
        }); 

}
```

Please suggest the way to utilize these powerful events through facebook channel in bot framework v4 node sdk.

I look forward for your response. thanks.

Comment: could you please anyone suggest ASAP. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all channels support all events.

onMembersRemoved -> Not supported by Facebook

onMessageReaction -> Not supported by Facebook

onReactionsAdded -> Not supported by Facebook

onReactionsRemoved -> No supported by Facebook

onTokenResponseEvent -> Which token?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) is a reference chart that show which channel supports which event activity.